# Highmaps, how to get marker position

Tags: position, zooming, marker, highmaps

I am working on a highmaps map of the world project and would like to zoom into a marker when the user clicks. I achieved this functionality by using the event in series in the below manner:

```
events: {
    click: function () {
    zoomInMarker();
  }

},
```

In my click function I am calling a function that gets Europe's coordinates. the function is defined as below:

```
function zoomInMarker () {

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(740, 1180, false);
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(-1730, -1470, false);
    chart.redraw();
 }
```

this works but which ever marker on the map I click, obviously always zooms in the same place that is Europe. How do i alter the zoomInMarker function to get the coordinates of the marker that was clicked. like for example using point.position instead of actual values like (740, 1180).

Comment: you would know if you were to search "map marker" on google

Comment: Well what Highmaps functionality are you using to make a marker?

Comment: I am defining map marker as an array with x and y positions and as you can see in my questions I am using the setExtremes functionality to zoom to particular coordinates. I want these coordinates to correspond to the map marker position every time a user click a marker.